# Dynamic ObservableCollection in TreeView?

Tags: c#, treeview, observablecollection

I Have this problem where I can´t load my data into my TreeView but I have to do it manually instead. My static solution looks like this:

```
public static ObservableCollection<ClassOfDoom> GetAll()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ClassOfDoom> listToReturn = new ObservableCollection<ClassOfDoom>();

        ClassOfDoom treeItem = null;

        OUViewModel ouvm = new OUViewModel();
        int[] tempOU = ouvm.HierarchyIntOU;
        int[] tempP = ouvm.HierarchyIntParent;

        treeItem = new ClassOfDoom("Root");
        treeItem.cID = tempOU[0];
        treeItem.pID = tempP[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < ouvm.HierarchyIntParent.Length; i++)
        {
            if (treeItem.cID == tempP[i])
            {
                treeItem.ClassOfDooms.Add(new ClassOfDoom(tempOU[i].ToString()));
                treeItem.ClassOfDooms.Last().pID = tempP[i];
                treeItem.ClassOfDooms.Last().cID = tempOU[i];
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ouvm.HierarchyIntParent.Length; i1++)
                {
                    if (treeItem.ClassOfDooms.Last().cID == tempP[i1])
                    {
                        treeItem.ClassOfDooms.Last().Countries.Add(new ClassOfDoom(tempOU[i1].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        listToReturn.Add(treeItem);    
        return listToReturn;
    }
```

This works but as you can see it´s only three levels and I wan´t a dynamic amount of levels. If someone wonders my ClassOfDooms list looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassOfDoom> ClassOfDooms
{
    get
    {
        if (classOfDooms == null) classOfDooms = new ObservableCollection<ClassOfDoom>();
        return classOfDooms;
    }
    set { classOfDooms = value; }
}
```

I want to state again that I have no trouble reading data from my database or anything like that. The TreeView get´s the right information just not all of it.

EDIT: I solved it myself like this:

```
    ClassOfDoom[] asdfDooms = new ClassOfDoom[ouvm.HierarchyIntParent.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ouvm.HierarchyIntParent.Length; i++)
    {
        asdfDooms[i] = new ClassOfDoom();
        asdfDooms[i].cID = tempOU[i];
        asdfDooms[i].pID = tempP[i];
        asdfDooms[i].name = tempPersonName + asdfDooms[i].cID.ToString();
    }
    for (int aint = 0; aint < ouvm.HierarchyIntParent.Length; aint++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ouvm.HierarchyIntParent.Length; i++)
        {
            if (asdfDooms[aint].cID == asdfDooms[i].pID)
            {
                asdfDooms[aint].classOfDooms.Add(asdfDooms[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    listToReturn.Add(asdfDooms[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) in conjunction with the [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control, this should ensure that changes made to the underlying data structure are reflected in the TreeView structure.

Comment: I looked quick at INotifyPropertyChanged Interface but didn´t quite understand how I could implement this in my code. Can you give me an example? Any more Info you need?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx, that gives a bit of background as to why it's necessary and where you would use it.